# Setting Metadata on an archived blob in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I would like to add a new header of the type "x-ms-meta-name:string-value" on a blob that is archived (currently rehydrating). However, Set Blob Properties and Set Blob Metadata REST APIs fail with "HTTP status code: 409 This operation is not permitted on an archived blob".

Is there any way I can add metadata headers to a blob in archive?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK as long as a blob is `Archived`, very few operations are permitted on the blob:

- You could read the properties of the blob.
- You could delete the blob.
- You could change the blob tier (from Archive to Hot or Cool).

Now coming to your question, in order to change the metadata of an archived blob, you will need to change its tier to either Hot or Cool (i.e. rehydrate the blob). Once the blob's tier is changed, you can change the metadata and then again change the blob's tier to Archive.

Please note that rehydrating blob is a time consuming operation (it may take up to a few hours). Not only that there's a rehydrating penalty (for the lack of better words) as well.

Comment: We also could get the more details about archive access tier from this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-storage-tiers#archive-access-tier).

Answer (score 1):

**While a blob is in archive storage, it is offline and cannot be read (except the metadata, which is online and available), copied, overwritten, or modified**. Nor can you take snapshots of a blob in archive storage. However, you may use existing operations to delete, list, get blob properties/metadata, or change the tier of your blob.

To read data in archive storage, you must first change the tier of the blob to hot or cool. This process is known as re-hydration and can take up to 15 hours to complete.
After that, you should be able to add the metadata.

More information can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-storage-tiers).